# Multi-Label classifier code error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, naivebayes, multilabel-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to train a classifier to label movies by genre. The plot of the movie might fall into more than one genre.
[This is what my dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuvOy.png)
I keep getting this error message when I try to figure out what the accuracy score are for each movie genre in the test set.
error message: 
**TypeError: 'FramePlotMethods' object is not iterable**

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

I got the movie data from https://github.com/davidsbatista/text-classification/blob/master/movies_genres_en.csv.bz2

**Here's the code from the beginning**

```
df = pd.read_csv("movies_genres_en.csv", delimiter='\t')
df.drop('plot_lang', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.info()

# using for loop get a count of movies by genre
df_genres = df.drop(['plot', 'title'], axis=1)
counts = []
categories = list(df_genres.columns.values)
for i in categories:
counts.append((i, df_genres[i].sum()))
df_stats = pd.DataFrame(counts, columns = ['genre','#movies'])
df_stats

# Create a fuction to clean the text
def clean_text(text):
text = text.lower()
text = re.sub(r"what's", "what is ", text)
text = re.sub(r"\'s", " ", text)
text = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have ", text)
text = re.sub(r"can't", "can not ", text)
text = re.sub(r"n't", " not ", text)
text = re.sub(r"i'm", "i am ", text)
text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are ", text)
text = re.sub(r"\'d", " would ", text)
text = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will ", text)
text = re.sub(r"\'scuse", " excuse ", text)
text = re.sub('\W', ' ', text)
text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text)
text = text.strip(' ')
return text    

# clean up the text in plot
df['plot'] = df['plot'].map(lambda com : clean_text(com))
```

## Split the data in to train and test sets

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, random_state=42, test_size = 0.33, 
shuffle=True)
x_train = train.plot
x_test = test.plot

# Define a pipeline combining a text feature extractor with multi lable 
classifier
NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
            ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(
                fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),
        ])

NB_pipeline.fit(x_train, train[genre])
prediction = NB_pipeline.predict(x_test)
accuracy_score(test[genre], prediction)
```

I get this error when I run the last code chunk
**TypeError: 'FramePlotMethods' object is not iterable**

What did I do wrong in creating the df?

Comment: It would be nice to have a "runable" example here. I don't really want to take the time to guess at what's in your dataframe. The image does not suffice, there's no guarantee you made the `df` properly in your code, and there are only 3 rows in the image and the last couple of columns are cut off. Can you give us a snippet that we can run out of the box? You don't have to build your full dataframe if it's too hard...but give us something.

Comment: I added the entire code above. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong with the df?

Comment: Plot is a column in your data frame. However, it is also a method in pandas. So, you may be confusing python with these commands train.plot and test.plot. They also look a bit like you have forgotten the round brackets, e.g. test.plot() and are trying to get plot as an attribute.

Comment: Makes sense...Thank you so much KRKirov